# Position a 3D model in front of the camera with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera that moves at certain positions/rotations. I have few 3D models. I want a 3D model to appear infront of the camera with a certain offset. They should be placed in the center of the camera. The distance between the camera and the 3D model should always stay the same and should not matter at what position the camera is at and at what rotation.

I have so far tried to do it this way:

```
void OnCamNewPosition(){

this.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width/2 + offset, Screen.height/2 + offset, Camera.main.nearClipPlane + offset));
}
```

This small bit of code works at certain times when camera is at certain positions but does not work always. Sometimes the 3D models is on left side of the camera instead of center and sometimes its way above the camera that we could only see half the 3D model.

Comment: Hi, it's been some time since I have worked with unity, but I think what you want to do is something like (pseudocode) `this.transform.position = Camera.main.position + Vector3.Forward * offset`

Comment: What @horotab says .. why go through screenspace if you can directly work on the 3D coordinates?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say there is no point in going trough screenspace.
If you target the cameras transform it will always be in center and also work for cameras that are not rendering to screen.

```
this.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + Vector3.forward * offset;
        
// if it should be attached to the camera
this.transform.SetParent(Camera.main.transform);
}
```